# python imaplib Как перейти в папку спам

Tags: python

Я перехожу в папку inbox:

```
mailbox.select("inbox")
```

Но как перейти в папку спам? Использую почту Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перейти в junk

```
mailbox.select('junk')
```